# CakePHP redirect routing

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-2.3

In my CakePHP 2.3 application, I want `example.com/come/Harry` to redirect `example.com/myworks/people/Harry`.

This works, but this connects.

```
Router::connect ('/come/:myname',
    array('controller' => 'myworks', 'action' => 'people'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('myname')
    )
);
```

I need a 301 redirection. I tried this:

```
Router::redirect ('/come/:myname',
    array('controller' => 'myworks', 'action' => 'people'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('myname')
    )
);
```

But it redirected to `example.com/myworks/people/`. How can I pass argument to my action while redirecting ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) you want to use `persist` rather than `pass` for redirects. This code should work as you want:

```
Router::redirect ('/come/*',
    array('controller' => 'myworks', 'action' => 'people',
          '?' => array('processed' => 1)),
    array(
        'persist' => array('myname')
    )
);
```

The reason is because you're generating a new url when you redirect:

> - **pass** is used to define which of the routed parameters should be
>     shifted into the pass array. Adding a parameter to pass will remove it
>     from the regular route array. Ex. 'pass' => array('slug')
> - **persist** is
>     used to define which route parameters should be automatically included
>     when generating new urls. You can override persistent parameters by
>     redefining them in a url or remove them by setting the parameter to
>     false. Ex. 'persist' => array('lang')

Comment: Is it possible to add static query string to URL? For example I want to add ```?processed=1``` to final URL.

Comment: @trante added that to my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are pretty much there, but you need to define your named params so that cake knows that the url is valid.

Reference, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action

```
Router::redirect (
    '/come/:myname',
    array('controller' => 'myworks', 'action' => 'people'),
    array(
        'myname' => '[a-z]+',
        'pass' => array('myname'),
        'status' => '301'
    ),
);
```

Comment: I inserted a lower case word for "myname". But this also redirects to ```example.com/myworks/people/```

Comment: When I try "Router::connect" it works, but "Router::redirect" doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Use following code

```
Router::redirect ('/come/*',
    array('controller' => 'myworks', 'action' => 'people'),
    array('params' => '[a-zA-Z0-9]+')
);
```